# Facebook API version detection

Tags: unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

We recently received this alert from Facebook on our Unity App.

*Your app has been making recent API calls to Graph API v2.0, which will reach the end of the 2-year deprecation window on Monday, August 8, 2016. Please migrate all calls to v2.1 or higher in order to avoid potential broken experiences.*

The SDK version is 6.2.2 which should be on API 2.2 - 2.4.

These are the APIs/Properties I'm using:

1. FB.Init(OnFbInit, OnHideUnity);
2. FB.API("/me?fields=name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET,GotFBData);
3. FB.IsLoggedIn;
4. FB.UserId
5. FB.AccessToken

Why is Facebook saying we are using API 2.0? Is it safe to ignore?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried asking on [gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @JoeBlow how did you get to the conclusion that (2.) is the wrong API?

And do you know if FB.Login is part of 2.0 or later?

Thanks,

Comment: @JoeBlow Check out the alert I get on Facebook dev page.  

![Facebook API Alert](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9385978/FacebookAPIs.PNG).

It looks like its the /me?fields=name right?

Comment: @AnthonyDemanuele, you're right; I was mistaken on that point, sorry.  I am still investigating this confusing issue!

Comment: Cheers @JoeBlow - Let me know if you find anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/

Then select your app. This will determine exactly which API version you are using.

If you wish to upgrade, this is the place, otherwise, safe to ignore.